# The three Cevian's are concurrent at point T. Show that all six small triangles have equal areas.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

[image]

It is given that $\Delta ART$, $\Delta BPT$, and $\Delta CQT$ have an area of one. I have no idea how to approach showing that all of the triangles have an equal area of one.

I shaded the three equal areas green in my construction.

Comment: If the other triangles have area D,E,F, you can get ratios between them because $\Delta ABP/\Delta ACP=\Delta TBP/\Delta TCP$.  The AM-GM inequality might help too.

Comment: I messed around with those ratios - because they're used in the proof of Ceva's Theorem - but I am not sure how they help me in proving this.

Comment: See http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h55209

Answer (score 1):

HINTS: $\frac{1+D}{1+E}=F$ and cyclic permutations give $DEF=1$ and $DE+EF+FD=3$.
Do you know the Arithmetic-Geometric Mean?

Comment: I am not familiar with the AM-GM.

Comment: The average of three positive numbers is greater than or equal to the cube root of their product, and they are only equal if the three numbers are equal.

Comment: Try to prove the AM-GM for two positive numbers, that their average is greater than or equal to the square-root of their product.